# How to read and analyze data from csv files to generate report according to user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot use any third party library. I have 1000 csv files as `.txt`. There are columns like date, max temp, min temp in the files.

The user will enter an year like 2009, the algorithm will read all files and store them into some data stucture and do calculations of the user entered year to get max or min to generate report for the user.
The report will tell max and min temp against its corresponding date which is another column in file.

What I have tried so far:

```
import csv
import glob
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

Max_temp = []
Min_temp = []
Mean_temp = []
Max_humidity = []
Min_humidity = []
Mean_humidity = []
dates = []

date = {}
```

storing specific column i.e date or temp in list

```
for column in d:
    dates.append(column[0])
for column in d:
    Max_temp.append(column[1])
for column in d:
    Min_temp.append(column[3])
for column in d:
    Mean_temp.append(column[2])
for column in d:
    Min_humidity.append(column[7])
for column in d:
    Mean_humidity.append(column[8])
for column in d:
    Max_humidity.append(column[9])
```

storing two lists of date and temp in a dictionary kindly tell me how to store two lists in dict one as key and other as value and one value for each key and in order

```
g = date.fromkeys(dates, Max_temp)
print(g)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what the user input is, since you're reading the data from CSV?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i didn't completely understand you question, but if you want to load csv files and perform analysis  on it you can use pandas.

```
'import pandas as pd
 file=pd.read_csv('filepath')
 max_temp=[]
 for row in file['column name']:
   max_temp.append(row)# the rows in column will append as list '
```